# Using NumPy to Extract an Array of Values from a Larger Array Based on Given Conditions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Specifically, these values are from a .fits file, which I am using astropy for.

Essentially, I am given a large array of data with objects each containing multiple columns with classifications and a corresponding row with a string or integer to identify them. For example, one object in the array could be

```
CLASS  == GALAXY
SPECPRIMARY = 1
PROGNAME == MAIN
ZWARNING == 0
PRIMTARGET == 128
SUBCLASS = STRINGHERE
FIBERID == INTEGERHERE
etc...
```

But, there are many columns and possible identifiers for each object. So, I am trying to use np.where to get only an array containing an array with these possible identifiers

```
                fits_data['CLASS'] == "GALAXY", 
                fits_data['SPECPRIMARY']==1,
                fits_data['PROGNAME']=='main',
                fits_data['ZWARNING']==0,
                fits_data['PRIMTARGET']==64 OR 128 OR 256
```

So, I guess it would look something like

```
allitems = np.where(fits_data['CLASS'] == "GALAXY", 
                fits_data['SPECPRIMARY']==1,
                fits_data['PROGNAME']=='main',
                fits_data['ZWARNING']==0,
                fits_data['PRIMTARGET']==(64 || 128 || 256))
```

But I know this isn't correct; I need the CLASS, SPECPRIMARY, PROGNAME, and ZWARNING to all have those exact values, whereas PRIMTARGET can be 64, 128, or 256.

Can anyone push me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `logical_and` and `logical_or` along with logical indexing is probably the best way here:

```
is_primtarget = reduce(np.logical_or, [fits_data['PRIMTARGET'] == 64,
                                       fits_data['PRIMTARGET'] == 128,
                                       fits_data['PRIMTARGET'] == 256])

combined = reduce(np.logical_and, [is_primtarget, 
                                   fits_data['CLASS'] == "GALAXY",
                                   ...])

# pick only those elements matching your requirements
selection = all[combined]
```

I like python's builtin `reduce` function here a lot, it applies the given function pairwise to all inputs in the iterable. So you get the `logical_or` or `logical_and` combination of all inputs.

Comment: `combined = (((fits_data['PRIMTARGET'] == 64) | (fits_data['PRIMTARGET'] == 128) | fits_data['PRIMTARGET'] == 256) & (fits_data['ZWARNING']==0) & (and so on...))` Observe braces around `==` statements due to low precedence of `|`.  (`a == b | c == d` means `a == (b | c) == d`, not `(a == b) | (c == d)`)

Comment: @pv. You should probably post this as an alternative answer - it doesn't really seem to be comment (if so, I don't get it).